# Linux VHDX size on Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, diskspace

I use Hyper-V on Windows 2016 Server and the problem is with size of Linux Virtual Machine's VHDX files. They are growing up in light speed. For instance I have Linux Mint and In Disk Usage Utility I see 125,4 GB available/133,7 GB total. The vhdx file is 40GB.

What I tried:
- shrink in Hyper-V,
- use e4defrag in VM,
- use dd if=/dev/zero of=wipefile bs=1M; sync; rm wipefile in VM.

After above instead 39GB I have 40GB. Any suggestions? What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

After couple of hours I found the solution.

1. First login to your guest OS (in my case Linux Mint) and clean the filesystem (delete cache/thumbnails files, apt-get clean, etc.).
2. Run these commands:

   `cat /dev/zero > zero.file
   sync
   rm zero.file`
3. Shutdown the machine.
4. Open command prompt on Hyper-V machine and type:

   `diskpart
   select vdisk file="D:\Hyper-V\somedisk.vhdx"
   attach vdisk readonly
   compact vdisk
   detach vdisk
   exit`

   Voila! The VHDX file is reduced in my case from 40GB to 18GB.