# How repair new (4.25) docker for windows after wsl compaction?

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2, diskpart

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946140/docker-desktop-wsl-ext4-vhdx-too-large) are instruction - how compact huge `ext4.vhdx` for docker. Earlier I can just rerun docker and that is. Now with fresh version 4.25 I got `Docker Desktop Privileged helper` popup and after it the following:

[image]

Docker version 2.0 started without any problems.

Any ideas hot to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart host OS fixed the issue