# Docker and WSL consumes lot of space in C Drive and Ubuntu not working error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, wsl-2

Recently I tried to run one docker image on my laptop. While running the docker image I wondered that it consumed around 60 GB of space in my C drive. Even if I uninstalled my docker desktop and all files related to wsl-2 and docker also from C drive. But around 50 GB of files are still in my C drive. I don't know how to delete the hidden files. And also currently my Ubuntu not working and I am getting the following error. [image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first issue, please take a look here:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9683
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699
[Docker Image Taking up Space After Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068185/docker-image-taking-up-space-after-deletion)
You will have a better understanding of how the files are actually saved and how to delete them,
for the second issue,
check if you have this file: %USERPROFILE%.wslconfig
try do delete it and restart wsl