Clean / Purge data in docker desktop with command line
I am using docker desktop 4.29 enterprise version. I have noticed that there are few cached data that is getting increase after every run. This is getting cached in folder "C:\Users\testdockervmadmin\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl". When I do Clean / Purge option manually then it is clearing this space. I want to perform same operation with powershell command.
Please suggest proper command that can just execute Clean / Purge with powershell command.
I tried my command ex:
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker network prune -f
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
docker system prune -a -f
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q);docker system prune --volumes -a -f
but nothing is working.
I have tried deleting this data with:
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl"
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data

but when I do this application showing some unexpected error while starting it.
Please suggest proper command that can just execute Clean / Purge with powershell command.

You can refer this if it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068185/docker-image-taking-up-space-after-deletion#68850149
